# Does rm work alphabetically?

Tags: linux, shell, rm

I had many files in a folder in which I accidentally ran `rm *` before interrupting.

It looks like files starting with a, b, and c are gone, but I am not sure, as I didn't know the name of all the files.

Can I rely on that `rm` works alphabetically so that I can know exactly which files that have been removed?

Comment: Off topic a bit, but if you are looking to recover the files you can use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDiskShare27) or the solutions given in [Where do files go when the rm command is issued?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10916/23934)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rm` does not necessarily work alphabetically, but it works in the order you supply its arguments (with `-r` it becomes more complicated, but that doesn't matter here). If you wrote exactly as you said, the `*` will expand to all file names in an alphabetical manner.

So **yes**, you have removed files alphabetically.

Try executing

```
echo *
```

in a directory to see in which order things show up. This is the same order that `rm *` would remove the files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they work alphabetically..

you can use strace command to check the sequence and how your kernel is working internally. Below is the strace command I used for rm command it translate * to alphabetic sequence.

surendra@linuxnix.com:~/scripts/temp/temp$ strace rm -rf *

execve("/bin/rm", ["rm", "-rf", "a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt", "d.txt"], [/* 43 vars */]) = 0

<--I have clipped the output-->

Where ever * is there, your bash shell will try to give all the combinations in this order. Some other commands which support this are cp, mv, find etc.